# ASP.NET Double validation, custom message for numbers only

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, validation

I have a validation for Fueling property which is a double.

```
[Display(Name = "Tankolás")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0} l", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    public double? Fueling { get; set; }
```

If I type letters instead of number in the input I get the error message: The value 'test' is not valid for Tankolás.

How could I change the error message?

Here is the view:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Fueling" class="control-label"></label>
                <input id="Fueling" asp-for="Fueling" class="form-control" placeholder="Tankolás" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Fueling" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

**EDIT - Full View code**

```
@model MainProject.Models.RoadRecord


@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Hozzáadás";
}
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/RoadRecords/create.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="container">
    <div class="text-center">
        <h2>Új Menetlevél hozzáadása</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-8">
            <form asp-action="Create">
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="UserId" />
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="LicencePlate" />

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Mileage" class="control-label"></label>
                    <div class="input-group-sm">
                        <input asp-for="Mileage" class="form-control" placeholder="Kilométer" />
                        <div id="mileageContainer" class="input-group-append">
                            <partial name="_ShowMileagePartialView.cshtml" model="@Model" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Mileage" class="text-danger"></span>
                    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Message))
                    {
                        <span class="text-danger">
                            @ViewBag.Message
                        </span>
                    }
                </div>

                @*
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="TimeStamp" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input type="datetime-local" asp-for="TimeStamp" class="form-control" value="@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm")" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="TimeStamp" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                *@

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Location" class="control-label"></label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input id="varos" type="text" asp-for="Location" class="form-control" aria-describedby="getLocationButton" />
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="getLocationButton">Pozícióm</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Location" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Type" class="control-label"></label>
                    <select id="selectType" asp-for="Type" class="form-control">
                        <option selected value="C">Céges</option>
                        <option value="M">Magán</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Fueling" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input id="Fueling" asp-for="Fueling" class="form-control" placeholder="Tankolás" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Fueling" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Note" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Note" class="form-control" placeholder="Megjegyzés" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Note" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()<input onclick="ConvertDouble()" type="submit" value="Hozzáadás" class="btn btn-primary w-100" />
                </div>
            </form>

            <a class="add" asp-action="Index" asp-route-licencePlate="@ViewBag.LicencePlate">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary w-100">
                    Vissza
                </button>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {

    <!--GEO Location-->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#getLocationButton').click(function () {
                $.getJSON('https://geolocation-db.com/json/')
                    .done(function (location) {
                        $('#country').html(location.country_name);
                        $('#state').html(location.state);
                        $('#city').html(location.city);
                        $('#latitude').html(location.latitude);
                        $('#longitude').html(location.longitude);
                        $('#ip').html(location.IPv4);
                        document.getElementById('varos').value = location.city;
                    });
            });
        });

        $.getJSON('https://geolocation-db.com/json/')
            .done(function (location) {
                console.log("kint");
                if (document.getElementById('varos').value == '') {
                    console.log("bent");
                    $('#country').html(location.country_name);
                    $('#state').html(location.state);
                    $('#city').html(location.city);
                    $('#latitude').html(location.latitude);
                    $('#longitude').html(location.longitude);
                    $('#ip').html(location.IPv4);
                    document.getElementById('varos').value = location.city;
                }
            });
    </script>

    <!--Get Milage-->
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                url: "../RoadRecords/ShowMileage?licencePlate=" + "@ViewBag.LicencePlate",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#mileageContainer").html(data);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    console.log(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        function ConvertDouble() {
            var param = $("#Fueling").val();
            if (param.indexOf(".") != -1) {
                param = param.replace(".", ",");
            }
            $("#Fueling").val(param);
        }
    </script>

}
```

Here is my full view code. I had to remove validation js because the fueling input, if I type for example 12,5 or 12.5 I got error message, so I removed it, and because of the Culture thing it's work with commas (I am from Hungary), and in the javascript I replace the dot with comma if the user type dot instead of comma.

Comment: Do you want to display error messages dynamically? For example, when typing `hello`, The error mesage will be :The value 'hello' is not valid for Tankolás.

Comment: No, I want something like, "You can use numbers only" or something like that (in my own language ofc)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `RegularExpression`  and `ErrorMessage` in your property to add rules and custom ErrorMessage

```
    [Display(Name = "Tankolás")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]*$",ErrorMessage = "You can use numbers only")]
    public double? Fueling { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work with if I type 12.5 or 12,5. Only if 12.

Comment: You just need to change regex to want you want (@"^(-?){0,1}[0-9]+([.]{1}[0-9]+){0,1}$")

Comment: Still got The value 'asdas' is not valid for Tankolás. If I type string

Comment: Can't override somehow?

Comment: Actually when you add `ErrorMessage` attribute, It will override.

Comment: Somehow it doesnt override for me, every other ErrorMessage work.

Comment: You can try reload your project and add the validation js like i provided.

Comment: Can we do without validation js? With validation js the if I type for example 12,5 and 12.5 will give error message, So I removed it

Comment: I edited my post with the full View code. Please check it

Comment: This is the front-end validation, so you need to use js, I didn't find anything unusual from your code